# nm-applet disappeared from awn indicator session area after installing d-bus-1.8.0

Tags: network-manager, indicator, awn

I have Ubuntu 13.10, since glib 2.32 failed to compile  some newer applications I compiled and installed glib 2.38 and its dependencies d-bus-1.8.0. When I booted in the morning I noticed that nm-applet was missing from indicator session area. At first I thought it was acting up of network manager daemon and I run:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Icon appeared on  `awn indicator session area` but doesn't show active device and connections list.

Then I run:

```
sudo nm-applet
```

wireless icon appeared in `A notification area (systray)` in place of `awn indicator session area`

And I get following messages in terminal:

```
 sudo nm-applet 
 ** Message: applet now removed from the notification area
 ** Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon

 ** (nm-applet:16151): WARNING **: Failed to register as an agent: (32) Session not found
 ** Message: applet now embedded in the notification area
```

Would anybody tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround that worked. D-bus-1.8.0 creates compatibily issue and needs new packages to get installed.

```
D-Bus Python-1.2.0
Py2cairo-1.10.0
PyCairo-1.10.0
PyGObject-2.28.6
PyGObject-3.12.1
PyGTK-2.24.0
PyXDG-0.25
```

But I didn't install them.

I found the workaround here:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=143985

```
sudo gedit /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.conf
```

I replaced all instances of deny with allow and saved.

I restarted session and it worked.